# Appolonius' problem: what is a tangent circle to a circle?

Tags: geometry

This picture of the problem was on a workshops registration that I attended five years ago... I already know what a tangent line is to a circle- what is a tangent circle to a circle though?

[image]

Comment: Two circles are tangent if they have a common tangent line at the point of intersection.

Comment: I believe, two circles are tangent if they lie in the same plane and have exactly one common point.